Ornstein-Uhlnbeck Process with Jumps
I am trying to simulate an OU Process (Vasicek version) with jumps and I would like to derive the drift and diffusion term when jumps are incorporated, which will enable me to perform monte carlo simulations.
In the absence of jumps we have the following drift:
$$
X_0e^{-kT}+v(1-e^{-kT})
$$
where $k$ mean reversion and $v$ long term mean and the following diffusion:
$$
σ\sqrt{\frac{(1-e^{-kT})}{2κ}}
$$
with the multiplication of a standard normal we can simulate via discretization the paths as shown below (having solved Ito's Lemma etc.)
$$
X_0e^{-kT}+v(1-e^{-kT}) + σ\sqrt{\frac{(1-e^{-kT})}{2κ}} N(0,1) 
$$
Lets leave aside any parameter estimation, say we have estimated $k,v,σ$.
Now instead of the above which comes from the equation
$$
dX_t=k(v-X_t)dt+σdW_t
$$
we want to estimate the drift and diffusion of the same process but with added Poisson jumps
$$
dX_t=k(v-X_t)dt+σdW_t+dJ_t
$$
where J is the jump component deriving from a Poisson process with intensity $λ$ (say 20 jumps/year) and a jump size distribution $N(μ_{jump},σ_{jump})$.
I have seen that the $J$ component is defined as:
$$
J_t=\sum_{i=1}^{N_i} Z_i
$$
where $N_i$ is a Poisson process with mean rate $λ$ and $Z_i$ are i.i.d jump sizes.
So, the ask - to my understanding - is to get some help on how to derive the expectation and variance of the Poisson process and add them to the vanilla case drift and diffusion respectively.
And as a second question - is there any way to model negative and positive only jumps seperately? Maybe we would need two Jump components say $J_1$ and $J_2$, the former with negative $μ_{jump}$ and the latter with positive only $μ_{jump}$?
Thanks in advance
